# Android WebView app with notifications

Tags: android, webview, notifications

I am making WebView app for a news website. I need help with setting notifications.

Steps that I have already done:

1. Set webView app.
2. Configure for firebase.
3. Defined basic MyMessageService and MyMessageIdService.
4. Tested push notification that I sent from Firebase to a device.

My question is: how to set my app to receive notification when new news is posted, or when a comment is made on liked news?

Thanks!

Comment: if the notifications need to be sent through different users its a little tricky because you need the token of each user and send a notification to each other, but firebase does not support auto sending notifications, you will need to send to all users a push notification telling them when a new post is made

Comment: check this video if you need to send notifications throught users : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQeHcgWxAFo    and this ones https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TGIMLdcl9E

Answer (score 0):

To send notifications on demand you have to do some things first:

- collect the firebase tokens of all the devices that are using your
  app.
- save all these tokens against users or profiles
- develop custom app server that will help you to send the
  notifications on devices using these firebase tokens.

to develop your app server you can use the code from androidhive.

[link to code of app server](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

for any further query you can ask in comment.

hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way to handle notifications automatically, beside fire base but I want to keep webView app?

Comment: may be there may be any but i have not gone through any of these dear.